# Hosting a file server on AWS subdirectory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, subdirectory, amazon-route53

I am trying to achieve something like below:

My domain **abc.com** is pointing to an ELB which in turn redirects traffic to EC2 servers where I run a Angular SSR.

I host some documents on a subdomain **docs.abc.com** which is hosted on S3.

Now, I want to host the documents in a way, such that the URLs for the documents are like **abc.com/documents/Readme.pdf**

Is there a nice way of doing it. I have approximately 10K documents.

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: Use a redirect on the abc.com server using htaccess or angular?

Comment: You can achieve this using CloudFront path based routing, or you can redirect/reverse proxy the URL from your ec2